# syncinc EVERYTHING between 2 computers

Tags: laptop, sync

i am a web developer, now i have WAMPserver on both of my machines

however, what I am truly interested in doing is syncing EVERYTHING on my home PC and my laptop

so basically, no matter what computer i am on, everything will be EXACTLY the same, right down to the file/mysql database/even firefox bookmarks

is there an easy way of doing this? or am i going to have to find ways to manually sync every single thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to set a main directory where you save everything and to use it as a large (paid) Dropbox folder on both computers.

Then, designate a primary computer and use Remote Desktop whenever you're at the other one.

Sync your bookmarks with [Xmarks](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xmarks-sync/) and in the event that you had to use the local computer and couldn't remote in to your other one, you would have all of your data.

Answer (score 1):

Run a minimal host OS on each, and use a virtualization package like VMWare, or VirtualBox, etc. to host the (virtual) machine you want synced.

Use scripts on the hosts to shut down the VM's (if running) and sync the virtual hard disk(s) between computers.

Might take a while to sync, depending on chosen software, image size, network speeds, etc.

An advantage to this is that as long as you are only using the VM on one machine at a time, you are probably legit on any 'one-machine-install' software licenses you own.